# JavaScript function to draw SVG elements

Tags: javascript, svg

Hello I would like to write a simple function that creates [svg](/questions/tagged/svg)circles  where I only have to specify the `x`, `y` coordinates.

JavaScript code is:

```
function cir(x, y){
    <circle cx="x" cy="y" r="10" fill="blue" />;
}
```

HTML code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <svg width="1024" height="768">

    cir(50, 50);

    </svg>

</body>

</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it doesn't work like this, you can't just put javascript in your html. You need to define `<script>...</script>` tags and put your javascript there. In that javascript you can then modify your html by using tag-ids

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can return some HTML using a [`template literal`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and add it to your SVG element.

```js
function cir(x, y) {
  return `<circle cx=${x} cy=${y} r="10" fill="blue" />`;
}

document.querySelector('svg').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', cir(50, 50));
```

```html
<svg width="1024" height="768"></svg>
```

Note: you should move your script to just before your `</body>` tag. That way the document will have time to load before the script is executed.

```
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

DOM resources on MDN:

- [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

EDIT

Now, if you wanted to include a form from which you can get the coordinates, you can do something like this.

```js
function cir(x, y) {
  return `<circle cx=${x} cy=${y} r="10" fill="blue" />`;
}

// Grab all the elements
const button = document.querySelector('.submit');
const svg = document.querySelector('svg');
const x = document.querySelector('.x');
const y = document.querySelector('.y');

// Add an event listener to the button
button.addEventListener('click', addShape, false);

function addShape(e) {

  // Prevent the form from submitting
  e.preventDefault();
  svg.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', cir(x.value, y.value));
}
```

```html
<form>
 <input class="x" type="text" placeholder="X coord" />
 <input class="y" type="text" placeholder="Y coord" />
 <button class="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<svg width="1024" height="768"></svg>
```

You can add more inputs for the radius and colour if you wanted.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to write the coordinates in the html page instead of the javascript page?

Comment: You mean add the info in a form that when it's submitted produces the circle?

Comment: Yes. I was thinking html is the page where I submit what/where I want to draw and the javascript is the mechanics behind the submission. Hope it makes sense...

Comment: Wow thanks. What I had in mind was the html page only displays the circles and the "sumission" is only the hidden html code. Like, the html code is "I invoke the circle function to draw 3 circles at coordinates 50,50 / 60,60 / 70,70" and the javascript code is "here's how the circle function works". Your code is even better.